# Is there a faster way to load mysqldumps?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speeding up mysql dumps and imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67117/speeding-up-mysql-dumps-and-imports)

`mysqldump` is reasonably fast, but dumps of a medium-sized database (20-30 megs) take several minutes to load using `mysql my_database < my_dump_file.sql`

Are there some mysql settings I can tune to speed up the load?  Is there a better way to load saved data?

I've experimented using the mysqlimport utility with CSV-based dumps. These load slightly--but not appreciably--faster.  I'm tempted to just copy raw database files around, but that seems like a bad idea.