# Fastest way of restoring MYSQL Dump

Tags: mysql

I have a dump of 2gb size and its taking more than 2 days to restore whole database and still going on.

I am using this command to restore my Database from dump file

mysql -uroot -ppassword new_db < old_db.sql

is there any faster way to do the same. so I can wrap up the Restoration task in one day or less.

Comment: There must be some problem, 2gb is not big enough to take 2 days

Comment: yes console comman is the optimal way!

Comment: A 2gb restore should take less than 5 minutes on a small server. You have other issues.

Comment: Thanks @hanky,@tahir,@rob my db has a lot of database constraints might this cause a huge delay and also I am using innodb as mysql engine. can you help me in what I am doing wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112069/is-there-a-faster-way-to-load-mysqldumps

Read jeffhiltz post.

Comment: Did you look at the errors log?