# MyISAM vs. InnoDB vs. others...?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

On a very limited environment (slow CPU, little RAM, but a lot of disk space), what would be the advantages of using different storage engine than MyISAM assuming an optimized php script (w/ using cache) daily performs a lot of read queries (SELECT) and almost no writes (m/b 5% - UPDATE queries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[At what point does MySQL INNODB fine tuning become a requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248420/at-what-point-does-mysql-innodb-fine-tuning-become-a-requirement/5250306#5250306)

This was addressed in a post I made a while back

In the post I reference other tuning articles

Please read this in its entirety