# MySQL > Table doesn't exist. But it does .. after database is restored from backup

Tags: php, mysql, centos, centos6, database-administration

At beginning we had application running perfectly on centos 6 , Since some updates were needed  on the server, We had to re-install softwares and packages on the server and use the application files from last backup we had.

**Having trouble to access tables:** If I run `SHOW TABLES ;` all tables are shown but if I try to query any of them e.g: `SELECT * FROM Users;` I get this error `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'myDatabaseName.Users' doesn't exist`

I also checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should#answer-11696069) which suggests to have ib* files in the root of the MySQL datadir (e.g. ibdata1, ib_logfile0 ib_logfile1) , in my case it seems to be in the right place and changing permission on mydatabase folder `chmod -R 660 myDatabaseName` and I did that

In my MySQL datadir I have the followings: `myDatabaseName, ibdata1 , ib_logfile0,  ib_logfile1 , mysql , mysql.sock , performance_schema`

Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Users;` are you sure your table name is `Users` not `users` ?

Comment: @TomaszTurkowski sure the table name is Users ,  looking forward to hear what you can help , thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128286/innodb-tables-exist-in-mysql-but-says-they-do-not-exist-after-copying-database-t?rq=1 hope that helps

Comment: according to 'myDatabaseName.Users' doesn't exist, the table Users may not be existing

Comment: Once check with `SHOW TABLES;`

Comment: @TomaszTurkowski But do you agree that SQL is case insensitive? In which case, both `SELECT * FROM Users;` and `SELECT * FROM users;` are equivalent.

Comment: did you success to do SELECT on another table

Comment: @RacilHilan yes I agree it's case sensitive. Not sure if it depends on configuration, but in my cases it is. If I will try to query select from (capitalised name of table) I'm getting table doesn't exist.

Comment: @phpfresher still the table is shown

Comment: @RacilHilan  sure my is case sensitive too

Comment: Hii.. i think may be ur connected to another database... once check it.. Once i did like that... I connected to a database and tried to fetch the data from a table in another database... Once check it...

Comment: @TomaszTurkowski and ikuchris what OS do you use? The standard SQL is case insensitive, but in MySQL case: Unix based are case sensitive while Windows and OSX are not. Here is a link from MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html. I personally use all-lower-case for database identifiers to avoid any issue.

Comment: @RacilHilan u're right locally I use OSX and is not case sensitive as you said while on production server I use centos and is case sensitive

Comment: @RacilHilan +1 locally i have OSX but on vm I'm using ubuntu and there's case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem by uninstalling and install again mysqlServer and taking the entire mysql directory `/var/lib/mysql` content from my backup to the new directory , and I have all tables and data accessible