# Efficiently loading a csv file into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

The current way I am loading the file is:

```
   load data local infile 'file_name' into table tableA  
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Is the optimal way to load in a table in a unix machine. Does it create the optimal table size? I want a table that takes up the smallest space.

Comment: Do you have a real-world memory usage problem with millions of rows? If not, you can most likely just go ahead.

Comment: Yes the table has million of rows.

Comment: Whatever means one uses to get the data into your table, once there it will occupy the same space...

Comment: I am worried that my ibdata1 file will increase exponentially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## MyISAM

If the table is MyISAM, you should do the following:

```
set bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
alter table tableA disable keys;
load data local infile 'file_name' into table tableA  
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
alter table tableA enable keys;
```

## InnoDB

If the table is InnoDB, you should do the following:

```
set bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
load data local infile 'file_name' into table tableA  
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
```

No only will this take up the least space (loading an empty table), but the rows will be buffered in a treelike structure in memory based on the [**bulk_insert_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size) for caching the data quicker during the reload.

If you are worried about ibdata1 exploding, you need to convert all InnoDB tables to use [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table). Please use my InnoDB Cleanup Steps : [Howto: Clean a mysql InnoDB storage engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)

Comment: Is it normal for a table to take 30 minutes load if the table has 30 million rows?

Comment: @cool_cs: How big is the CSV?  What indexes exist in the table?  Are there any before/after `INSERT` triggers defined?  How fast are the local and remote disks?  How fast is the network?  So many issues at play here.