# Calculated mysql5 table size different from ibdata

Tags: mysql, database, size

I am trying to calculate the total size of all tables in mysql:

```
SELECT sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Mb" FROM information_schema.TABLES;

+--------------+
| Mb           |
+--------------+
| 942.02298263 | 
+--------------+
```

The size of /opt/mysql5/data/ibdata is 3.1 GB. Why is there such a difference between the two numbers?

Comment: What table schemas are you using?

Comment: @Drewness innodb and some myisam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ibdata` is the busiest file in the InnoDB infrastructure. It houses many different classes of information.

- Table data
- Table indexes
- Table metadata
- MVCC data

You can see a graphic representation [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing).

Here are several links to discussions on this topic.

- [MySQL: reducing ibdata file size for MyISAM tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635383/mysql-reducing-ibdata-file-size-for-myisam-tables)
- [Best way to reduce the size of ibdata](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/what-is-the-best-way-to-reduce-the-size-of-ibdata-in-mysql/8983#8983)
- And of course the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-configuration.html)

What (if any) action you choose will obviously depend on your setup and goals. I would however consider adjusting the `inndb_log_file_size` in your `my.cnf` file as these can get very large very quickly.