# Innodb table with many deletes and inserts - is there any disk space wasted?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I have a big (500GB) innodb table that I'm performing many inserts as well as deletes on.
innodb_file_per_table is set in my var configuration. I know it might contain a lot of 'wasted' disk space, due to the nature of innodb, question is how much is expected and if there is a way to find out that number in my specific table. From what I understand it re-uses the not-used space that is created during `delete` so if I keep doing `inserts` I shouldn't experience any major diff when performing a [re-claim procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)? As a thumb rule, what are the high and low limits for the disk space waste and what usage patterns define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have innodb_file_per_table enabled, I have some good news. You can do a lot more than defrag the table. You can shrink the table. In order to find out how much space you will reclaim follow this procedure:

For these steps, let's use the InnoDB table `mydb.mytable`

```
GIVEN_DB=mydb
GIVEN_TB=mytable
MYSQL_CONN="-root -p...."
SQLSTMT="SELECT data_length+index_length FROM information_schema.tables WHERE"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} table_schema='${GIVEN_DB}' AND table_name='${GIVEN_TB}'"
IBDSIZE=`ls -l /var/lib/mysql/${GIVEN_DB}/${GIVEN_TB}.ibd | awk '{print $5}'`
TBLSIZE=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} --skip-column-names -Ae"${SQLSTMT}"`
(( FRGSIZE = IBDSIZE - TBLSIZE ))
FRAGPCT=`echo ${FRGSIZE}00/${IBDSIZE}|bc`
echo ${IBDSIZE} ${TBLSIZE} ${FRGSIZE} ${FRAGPCT}
```

This will print 4 numbers

- `IBDSIZE` : Size of InnoDB Individual Tablespace from the OS Viewpoint
- `TBLSIZE` : Size of InnoDB Table from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA Database
- `FRGSIZE` : Difference of `IBDSIZE` and `TBLSIZE` (in Bytes)
- `FRAGPCT` : Percentage Difference of `IBDSIZE` and `TBLSIZE`

If you do not like how high `FRAGPCT` is, there are three ways to shrink `mydb.mytable`:

OPTION 1 : `OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable;`

OPTION 2 : `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;`

OPTION 3 : Run the Compression in Stages

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytabletmp LIKE mydb.mytable;
INSERT INTO mydb.mytabletmp SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable;
DROP TABLE mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytabletmp RENAME mydb.mytable;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Lost you a bit. How/where should I run the first chunk of code you wrote (starts with "GIVEN_DB"). Sraight from bash?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL / InnoDB provides no function to 'free up' space, but it will re-use the space from the deleted rows for future insert statements.

Running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` ([more information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html)) periodically will help to maximize the amount you can re-use as well as increase I/O performance (it's basically like defrag for your database).