# mysql database have larger size

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, myisam

I have a database and that contain many tables , but all of them store text and full tables size is  less than **10 MB** , but the database file on server have larger than **1 GB**

The tables uses MyIASM , where is the problem ?

thanks

Comment: Which database file? is it ibdata1? Do you have any InnoDB tables? Did you have any such tables before and have you deleted them? If so, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql

Comment: @Ata maybe you should look if you can keep the TEXT datatype in one table. table fragmentation is caused by deleting/updating from table that have non fixed sizes like varchar / text columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html) for reducing disk usage on MyISAM tables (usually after deleting lot of data from them or doing major changes in structure).

For InnoDB, that is quite more challenging, see [Howto: Clean a mysql InnoDB storage engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine)