# MYSQL5.5 INNODB optimazation

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, innodb

looking to optimize mysql5.5 databases for INNODB. I have tried the link

Note: The databases also contains MYISAM tables.

[Howto: Clean a mysql InnoDB storage engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)

As per the instructions I have dropped all databases as well as ibdata* and ib_logfile* and made changes in my.cnf like

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
```

Now on restoring the backup, not only mysql storing INNODB tables in separate files, but it is doing it for MYISAM tables as well.
This is resulting in MYISAM database unusable.

when I am trying to access the website having MYISAM tables I am getting the error - **Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error**

Can't makeout why mysql is storing MYISAM tables in separate files.
Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK MyISAM always stores tables in their own files (3 files per table: .MYI, .MYD and .frm).

Answer (score 0):

- AFAIK MyISAM always stores tables in their own files (3 files per table: .MYI, .MYD and .frm).
- It is **not allowed** to remove the ibdata file. Do you have a backup of that file? To move from single file to file per table you need to do as stated here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html (see under "Enabling and Disabling Multiple Tablespaces")

Comment: Yes I have a backup of those files.does ibdata file contains any information relate to MYISAM tables.

Comment: I think you better restore them, and follow the instructions in the link I sent to make InnoDB create the tables in their own files (from the ibdata files).