# Is Magento reaching out to Fedex and UPS on each product page load?

Tags: magento, fedex, ups

I have a magento site with about 200 products and the product pageloads take over 14 seconds. I've done many of the often suggested speedups with no real difference in speed. So I asked my webhost for some help with optimizing and they did some sort of php trace and noticed: "a number of remote connections made to ws.fedex.com" which were slowing the page loading down. I disabled fedex as a shipping method and lo and behold the page load times went down by 7 seconds or so.

So my question is -- Does magento by default make connections to shipping carriers on each product page load? Or could it be a module I'm using that's doing this? How would I go about hunting this down in the code?

Comment: Are you using any custom module or display shipping related info on this page?

Comment: That sounds improbable and should not really be an issue with all cache turned on. Either way - 7 seconds is still unacceptable and one of the downsides with Magento. It will hardly run without at least VPS hosting, a shared environment is out of the question.

Comment: I ended up figuring out that it was an extension I had installed that was doing it and I reconfigured its settings to stop doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is 'no'. Magento does not do that. To hunt down speed snags in the code, use the Varien Profiler. The everso useful [Inchoo blog has detailed instructions for getting the Varien Profiler working](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/keeping-your-magento-fit-with-built-in-profiler/).

For the question 'does your particular set up do that?' according to your host, the answer is 'yes'. But it shouldn't. I recommend switching your theme to the Magento default and try to find out if your server is still hitting ws.fedex.com. If it is, start disabling any non-core modules [system->configuration->advanced] one at a time to see if you can identify which one is hitting ws.fedex.com.

Try to run those tests with cache and compiler both off.

That leaves you with a 7 second page load and the whole new question 'How do I make my Magento site faster'. As Christoffer commented, dedicated hosting will help, specialist hosting is recommended.

You mentioned you implemented some common ways to speed up Magento without much difference (normally there is a difference esp. for caching). So here are [some pointers to get you started on Magento speed issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588867/what-is-the-best-method-to-remedy-magento-being-slow-with-20-000-products/22595346#22595346). The Varien profiler will probably be of most use to you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the debugging tips! I ended up figuring out that it was an extension I had installed that was doing it and I reconfigured its settings to stop doing that.