# MySQL: Can't create table: errno -1

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm having a weird issue with MySQL, I can't create a table. 
The table used to exist, it's part of a job that loads to a staging table every day, then truncates that table at the end. After months, the table disappeared (maybe someone dropped it, doesn't matter) and I went to rebuild it but I get this error:

```
Level   Code    Message
Error   1005    Can't create table 'apps.raw_appsites_stage' (errno: -1)
```

I can't drop the table or rebuild it.  But if change the table name at all I can build it.
So it seems the table got dropped but the namespace is still reserved or stuck in limbo on the back-end.

Here's the ddl that doesn't work:

```
create table raw_appsites_stage(t int);
```

But this ddl does work:

```
create table raw_appsites_stage_1(t int);
```

I'm using an RDS instance so I don't have much access to the server itself.  Here's the version info:

```
Variable_name   Value
innodb_version  5.5.40
protocol_version    10
slave_type_conversions  
version 5.5.40-log
version_comment Source distribution
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
```

How can I see where this name is being held onto and why it won't let me drop or create a table with this name?

**UPDATE**
I tried a rename on that table and got a new error I've never seen before:

```
Can't find file: './apps/raw_appsites_stage.frm' (errno: 2)
```

So it's definitely something funky on the back-end, but this being and RDS instance I don't have access to the machine OS.
Anyone know of a fix for this? DO I need to wait on AWS support?

Thanks

Comment: Use `create table if not exists raw_appsites_stage(t int);`

Comment: @juergend : I get the exact same error running that command.  The issue is not that I'm trying to create that already exists.  The issue is that table-name is in limbo, MySQL says no table exists with that name, but also won't let me create a new table with that name.

Comment: what happens if you select * from raw_appsites_stage?  You should try drop table if exists raw_appsites_stage

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: Select * FROM ... = "Table 'apps.raw_appsites_stage' doesn't exist",  "Drop table if exists" is fine because MySQL thinks it doesn't exist ... until I try to create it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, if you are using `InnoDB` as engine. Somehow, you lost the `raw_appsites_stage.frm` and `raw_appsites_stage.ibd` files. The data dictionary still has an entry for that table.

Now you can't drop table as mysqld will look for .frm file first.

you can either try `check` and `repair table raw_appsites_stage` (if not InnoDB)

or, backup ibdata1 by `mysqldump` then delete ibdata1 and restore. Details [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)

Comment: thanks, good info. Unfortunately(?) I am using Innodb so I can't use "repair table", and "check table raw_appsites_stage;" returned "ERROR: Table 'apps.raw_appsites_stage' doesn't exist", and since this is RDS I can't access the filesystem as described in that very detailed link you posted.