# Optimize innodb table when innodb_file_per_table disable

Tags: mysql, performance

I am using innodb. I have a problem with app performance. When I run `mysqlturner.pl` I get:

[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 8G (Tables: 1890)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 1890

Ok, i have run mysqlcheck -p --optimize db.
I have diceded that innodb_file_per_table is disabled. The last 2 years a database wasn't reindex. How I can do it?

1. Make mysqldump?
2. Stop mysql serice?
3. insert enable innodb_file_per_table into my.cnf?
4. Start mysql serice?
5. Import from mysqldump?
6. run mysqlcheck -p --optimize db?

Will everything be ok?

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need to drop the tables after dump but before restore; and pretty sure the shared ibdata will not shrink.

Comment: how "sure the shared ibdata will not shrink"?

Comment: I haven't dug into the details for a couple years, but last I recall the only supported way to shrink the main `ibdata1` file was to backup your data, uninstall and reinstall MySQL Server, then restore.

Answer (score 1):

**Tables fragmented**

Bogus.

All InnoDB tables are always (according to that tool) fragmented.

In reality, only 1 table in 1000 needs to be defragmented.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE foo;` will defrag a single table.  But, again, I say "don't bother".

**ibdata1 bloated**

On the other hand...  If you are concerned about the size of ibdata1 *and* Data_free (`SHOW TABLE STATUS`) shows that a large chunk of ibdata1 is "free", then the only cure is painful:  As already mentioned:  dump, stop, remove ibdata1, restart, reload.

But... If you don't have enough disk space to dump everything, you are in deep weeds.

You have 8GB of tables?  (Sum Data_length and Index_length across all InnoDB tables.)  If ibdata1 is, say 10GB, don't bother.  If it is 100GB, then you have a lot of wasted space.  But if you are not running out of disk space, again I say "don't bother".

If you are running out of disk space *and* ibdata1 seems to have a lot "free", then do the dump etc.  But additionally:  If you have 1890 tables, probably most are "tiny".  Maybe a few are somewhat big?  Maybe some table fluctuates dramatically in size (eg, add a million rows, then delete most of them)?  I suggest having innodb_file_per_table ON when creating big or fluctuating tables; OFF for tiny tables.

Tiny tables take less space when living in ibdata1; big/fluctuating tables can be cleaned up if needed via `OPTIMIZE` *if* ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would do it. Take a backup before you start and test the entire process out first on an copy of the host, esp. the exact mysqldump command, you don't want databases like 'information_schema' in the dump.

Also ensure that other services cannot connect to your db once you start the export - any data they change would be lost during the import.

There are detailed instructions in this previous question:
[Howto: Clean a mysql InnoDB storage engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261)

Comment: is it only way(innodb enable per table) for fragmented tables?