# MySQL : Performance import DUMP

Tags: mysql, performance, import, dump

I'm experiencing performance issues when importing a dump.

One of our providers has given us a dump of around 6 GB.

To import this dump, I have a remote server with the following configuration:
CPU: AMD EPYC 7313P
RAM: 128 GB
Disks: 2 x 1.92 TB NVMe
OS: Windows 2022 64-bit

I can see from Windows monitoring tools that I'm only utilizing a small portion of my processor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfSlk.png)

Do you have any solutions to enhance CPU usage during the dump import?

Thank you

Comment: LVM allows nearly-instantaneous backup and restore, regardless of size.  But it requires OS setup and it has limitations.

Comment: You say "remote" -- is the network saturated?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing specific to question would be to import dump from the other disk where db is stored.

- [Speeding up mysql dumps and imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67117/speeding-up-mysql-dumps-and-imports)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster

For the rest there are many solutions for tweaking the import/export. If it's a critical recurring process then it might worth optimizing it, otherwise just let it run.

You can also use a separate managed server in cloud, use it for the import extract only the data you need then stop it.